# Why isn't my WHERE clause short-circuiting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some queries that do "perm" checks in a where clause. It more or less looks like this:

```
where (r IS NULL) and ((team.visibility = 6)
  or ((team.visibility = 3) and (user)-[:FRIEND]- (:User{userid:team.owner}))
  or ((team.visibility = 4) and (user)-[:FRIEND*1..2]-(:User{userid:team.owner}))
  or ((team.visibility = 5) and (user)-[:FRIEND]-(:User)-[:HAS]->(:UserTeamRef)-[:JOINED]->(team)))
```

match (team)<-[:JOINED|SUSPENDED]-(members:UserTeamRef)

The Friend of Friend (foaf) for team.visibility = 4 is clearly an expensive operation. It is executed every query even though in the data set I am testing against does not have a single team with visibility = 4.

My expectation would be that 98% of the time the query would short-circuit on the team.visibility = 6, because 98% of teams have that perm value. I would also expect that with 0 teams at visibility = 4, that the foaf match would *never* happen.

What gives?

[image: Query Plan with team.visibility=4]

[image: Query plan w/o team.visibility=4]

Comment: Can you PROFILE your query and add the query plan (with all elements expanded) to your question?

Comment: Query plan included

Comment: Thanks, I believe the critical operation is the Projection operation with 167,491 db hits. Can you confirm that the WHERE clause in the profiled query is identical to the one you provided? And then can you let us know, if you remove the entire middle condition for `team.visibility = 4`, how do the db hits change for that operation, and do the number of output rows from that operation change at all?

Comment: it is the same, although the profile was done on a slightly different query than the original (no change to where clause, there was a separate indexing issue.)

Removing the team.visibility=4 check has *significant* performance improvement. I can provide a prof for that query if you like. The node in question (167k) drops to around <1000 if I remember correctly.

Great Q regarding the number of output rows. The query uses a LIMIT and because there is a reasonable amount of data in the set, I always see $limit rows. I can remove the limit and let you know.

Comment: I have re-posted with a more accurate version of where clause (I had made an optimization I thought was equivalent, but apparently was not.) So, I have kind of mucked things up a bit. The two plans posted show the most relevant nodes, and are queries run back-2-back against same data set with and w/o team.visibility=4.

Queries (w/o LIMIT) return same # of rows.

Comment: And one more comment. The indexing issue I was running into was that an index was NOT being used for this form:
    match (n:Node{indexField:$indexValue})
I had to use 
    match (n:Node) where n.indexField = $indexValue
(I did not bother looking at adding a hint)

is it possible that the where clause use of the form:
    (user)-[:FRIEND]- (:User{userid:team.owner})
is NOT using the User.userid index?

Comment: Thanks! Can you also add the stuff at the bottom after running the PROFILEs, which includes the Cypher runtime, total db hits, etc?